# C# - Excel - How to delete visible rows after AutoFilter?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2015, excel-2013, excel-interop

I´m working on a little commandline tool to extract some data from an excel sheet.

I want to delete all rows which are visible after applying an AutoFilter.

Unfortunately, I just don´t know how to continue.
After some searching, I did not find a working answer for me.

Here is what I´ve got so far:

```
        oXL = new Excel.Application();
        oXL.Visible = false;
        oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(source);
        oXS = (Excel.Worksheet)oWB.Sheets[1];

        Excel.Range filter = oXS.UsedRange;
        filter.AutoFilter(8, "<>text to filter");
```

How do I delete all rows which are shown after filtering?

Thanks.

CRowland

Answer (score 1):

```
Excel.Range filter = XlSheet_1.UsedRange;
filter.AutoFilter(8, "<>text to filter");
filter.Delete(XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a bit late for an answer but I put it for reference.
Every `Excel.Range` object has a `Delete()` method:

```
    Excel.Range filter = oXS.UsedRange;
    filter.AutoFilter(8, "<>text to filter");
    filter.AutoFilter.Range.Delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look on this VBA reference. BTW, you will need to set up the `EnableAutoFilter` value for the worksheet before you operate the `AutoFilter` function.

https://danwagner.co/how-to-delete-rows-with-range-autofilter/