# Eliminate a series of rows in C# Excel Interop

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have a problem.

I need to know if there is a way to delete a series of rows in C# Excel Interop without reading every single cell for a match. I have a 10k row excel sheet and I only want to delete the ones I want but using a `for` to look for the row and delete it takes an absurd amount of time. In fact it´s faster to open the file, apply a filter and delete the rows but I want to make all on code.

Someone knows a way to do it?

Comment: You should post the code that you have so that people can analyze why it might be slow and give you more advice.  Without a starting point though we don't even know what you have tried.

Comment: You might also want to look at ways to manipulate an Excel file that don't require that you open Excel (OpenXML SDK, EPPlus, perhaps others).  Excel interop relies on Excel to do the work.  You can also get a good ide of how to do things with interop by opening the Macro recorder, doing your operations by hand, and looking at what VBA code the recorder spits out.  It's often pretty good at giving you some ideas.  But, as @carter says, you aren't going to get anything other than general suggestions unless you post your "takes an absurd amount of time" code

Comment: Try using the filter technique in C# rather than For loop.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39658770/2521004) to get started.